# Graficar una serie de tiempo en R - class zoo

Tags: r

El código de abajo es para abrir una hoja de excel y transformarla en serie de tiempo para poder analizar unas tendencias.

```
library("openxlsx")
Sob <- read.xlsx("Libro1.xlsx","Soberanos")
Sob.zoo <- as.zoo(Sob[,-1], order.by = as.Date(Sob[,1],origin="1899-12-30"))
```

Quisiera saber como separar la serie de tiempo en rangos específicos y graficarla. Estoy usando en código de abajo pero salen errores.

```
chart.TimeSeries(Bono["04-01-2019/05-11-2019"], main = "Tendencia")
```

*Error in attributes(xx) <- c(attributes(xx), list(...)) :
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In periodicity(y) : can not calculate periodicity of empty object
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In max(start, as.numeric(s), na.rm = TRUE) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(end, as.numeric(e), na.rm = TRUE) :
no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf*

Comment: ¿Que es `Bono`?

Comment: Bono es el nombre de la columna en excel que muestra cantidades en miles

Comment: Entonces lo que no entiendo es, que intentas hacer con `Bono["04-01-2019/05-11-2019"]`¿que relación tiene `Bono` con `sub.zoo`? ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo de los datos?, ayudaría que agregues la salida de `str(Bono)`